# I cant even call a function on different file of Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this annoying bug within my code, which is very very simple. I've tried alot of things, but I couldn't get it to work.

I have tried using using the `script` tag, and put some code in there, like

```
<script>
function lol() {
   alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
```

and then I did this

```
<body onload="lol();">
</body>
```

Don't get me wrong, this code works perfectly. Except when I am using code from a javascript file outside of my index.html file.

```
<script src="src/other/setriox.js"></script>
```

The javascript file named setriox.js has a function called 
`function loled()` which holds a simple function of `alert("Hello World!");`

Now, when I do the SAME EXACT thing with the `body onload`

```
<body onload="loled();">
</body>
```

It is not being called. The path to the setriox.js is perfectly fine, not miss spelling or anything like that.

Here is my github if you want to look deeper on why the `loled()` function is not being called.

https://github.com/Setriox/Portfolio

Comment: Are there error messages?

Comment: Sadly no. Nothing ever happens actually.

Comment: Can't you just call it in your script by `window.onload = function() { //all the lols you want to invoke here }` and not using the `<body>` tag

Comment: is your script loaded before your body? Either way a better approach would be to use the 'DOMContentLoaded' event rather than the body onload.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working, I tried window.onload = lol(); and nothing happens.

Comment: My script is loaded before the body. Look in my GitHub, I provided a link.

Comment: `window.onload = function() {loled(); lol(); }`, bro. Read carefully

Comment: The loled function is from another javscript file.

Comment: It doesn't metter since both are in the `window` scope

Comment: The loled function holds alert("Hello World!"), and that code is not being executed.

Comment: In your github repo, striox.js defines `function lol` at [line 4](https://github.com/Setriox/Portfolio/blob/master/src/other/setriox.js#L4), not `function loled`.

Comment: Haha, woops. I probably got it reversed, fixing it right now.

Comment: Still, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you have not closed your comment on the [js file](https://github.com/Setriox/Portfolio/blob/master/src/other/setriox.js#L8)?

Comment: No, it isnt. The comment just comments out all the code below, not above. Thanks anyways.

Comment: `/*` without a matching `*/` makes the entire file syntactically invalid.  Parsing isn't successful so none of the code in it will ever be executed.

Comment: Let me check on that.